# undefined reference to 'av_rdft_init(int, RDFTransformType)'

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk, libavcodec

I'm trying to integrate ffmpeg library to an android ndk project. I followed [this](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) documentation. When i try to call a method from avcodec library like as av_malloc, there is no problem. But when i try to call av_rdft_init or av_rdft_calc methods, ndk gives errors like as;

```
 error: undefined reference to 'av_rdft_init(int, RDFTransformType)'  
 error: undefined reference to 'av_rdft_calc(RDFTContext*)'
```

I can see those methods in header file and also see in libavcodec.so file's symbol table but could not build with ndk.

Any ideas to fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by adding LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true to android makefile